# Find taylor series of $ \frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}} $

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have to find the taylor series at x = 0 of $ \frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}} $
I understand you can differentiate but is there an easier way?

Comment: are you allowed to do that and would it still give the same answer?

Comment: I suspect the following is a big hint: $1/(1-t)=\sum t^n$ and there is a formula for the product of power series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting the expression by $f(x)$
$$f(x) = \frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}}$$
and applying $\ln$ to both sides, we get
$$\ln f(x) = 100\ln(1+x) - 40\ln(1-2x) - 60\ln(1+2x)$$
Now, you can use the expansion for $\ln(1\pm x)$ around $x = 0$ and then go back.

However, if you only need the expansion up to some term, you can apply the binomial expansion to each bracket and then collect terms in big $O$ or small $o$ notations.

Comment: getting the Taylor series of $\ln f(x)$ does not automatically give the Taylor series of $f(x)$...

Comment: I  only need it up to x^2 so I got lnf(x) = 60x + 150x^2 how do i go back?

Comment: @Hello Now, exponentiate and use the expansion of $e$. But as I have mentioned, you can use the binomial expansion (see the comment above by Calvin Khor)

Comment: Thanks I managed to get the answer using the exponential way and it matched the mark scheme. 1+60x +1950x^2 for those wondering.

Comment: @Hello the method I gave lets you write the full expansion at once, not just the first few terms